# json_encode(array) insertion in db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, insert

My array has some values

```
  0 => '1'
  1 => 'moisturizer'
  2 => 'skincare'
```

I am trying to convert that array to string, I am currently using `json_encode`

```
$value = array_shift( $val_ary ); //val_ary is that array
echo json_encode($value); // This will echo my data like

["1","moisturizer","skincare"]
```

later I would like to insert those values in my mysql db table

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category)
VALUES ('json_encode($value)')");
```

Should this work?

Or shall I `json_decode` before I insert in db?

Comment: Did you try inserting to DB?

Comment: No. If you json-encode something, it becomes a monolithic string. MySQL is **NOT** json-aware, and your query will fail, trying to stuff the json string into the `sno` field and leaving type/category undefined.

Comment: WHy are you JSON encoding in the first place, and trying to insert one string value when your list of columns has three fields identified?

Comment: @MarkBaker My list of columns would be random. I am just trying on smaller example at the moment.

Comment: why do you want to use json in first place? I don't think you need that for inserting values to DB.

Answer (score 3):

`json_encode(array)` returns a json string, while values for MySQL insert should be (value1,value2,...). `json_decode(json_string)` return an array, and `implode` glues the arrays pieces with "," separating the array objects. There is no need to convert it to json if the only thing you do is to insert it to the DB. Usually json is being used for passing info between pages/servers (AJAX calls for example) or saving an array as a string in a DB

**If you get the data as json:**

```
$value = json_encode(array(value1,value2,...))
```

do

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category) 
    VALUES ('".implode(",",json_decode($value))."')");
```

**if you get the data as array:**

```
$value = array(value1,value2,...)
```

do

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category) 
    VALUES ('".implode(",",$value)."')");
```

Comment: The `.` character is used for string concatenation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need JSON here. You can try do these,

```
$arr = array(0 => '1', 1 => 'moisturizer', 2 => 'skincare');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category) VALUES ('{$arr[0]}', '{$arr[1]}', '{$arr[2]}')");
```

If your array is multidimensional then you can use `foreach` loop to insert the data,

```
$values = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
   $values[] = "('{$v[0]}', '{$v[1]}', '{$v[2]}')";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category) VALUES ".implode(',', $values));
```

**Note:** Don't use mysql_* functions, they will be deprecated soon. Instead use PDO or MySqli functions.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a way to represent data as a string.  It's used mainly to transport data.

JSON has no place here, just [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) the data, and use it in the query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE (sno, type, category) VALUES ".
    "(" . implode(",", $value) . ")");
```